# VPN on router: Mac OS ignore DNS

Tags: dns, vpn, macos, router, asus

hopefully someone can help because even the VPN customer care could not.

I have setup a VPN (OpenVPN) on my router (Asus AC56U) like I did other a lot of other times.
In the past, everything worked fine.

This time, not: on **Mac Catalina** I get the right IP address, but **it skip straight forward the VPN DNS and leaks the ISP ones.** This happens both cable and WiFi.

I tried then to check other devices while connected WiFi to router, and they work as intended, with no bad DNS.
I tried on terminal `scutil --dns` and flush the DNS cache, but this has not helped. What make me crazy is that the configuration is on the router, not on the Mac, but the Mac is the only client that skip the DNS.
If I use the official VPN client app to connect, it works fine on Mac too.
I found a workaround, but it can't be considered a stable solution: while under the VPN app I wrote down the DNS I was connected to and dropped into the router config. As soon the VPN provider will change it, will need to change them too.

Any better idea?